# How to analyze line of code?

Tags: c#

What would be steps to analyze and understand this code?

Code: the `Write` method is called by the `SerialPort` object (of the `SerialPort` class)

```
SerialPort.Write(new byte[1] { (byte)PacketTypeShimmer2.START_STREAMING_COMMAND }, 0, 1);
```

This is the enumerator called.

```
public enum PacketTypeShimmer2 : byte
{   ....
    START_STREAMING_COMMAND = 0x07,
    ....
};
```

Comment: So far it is way too broad for SO. Have you read documentation on the method? Have you tried to declare variables for each parameter and use values? What exact part of the statement is unclear to you?

Comment: @geft, I've edited your post to match current answers and add question. Please check if it matches your intentions (rollback if needed). For future posts try to provide question and smallest possible code sample.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, I was just confused about the syntax, nothing to do with parameter values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it'll help to break things down into smaller pieces. First, your `enum` inherits from `byte` so can be cast to a `byte`. That's key in understanding the rest.

Next, let's look at the `SerialPort.Write` method. It takes the following parameters:

1. a `byte[]` - the data to write
2. an int - the offset (where to start in the byte array)
3. an int - the length (how far to read in the byte array)

So, now that we know that, let's look at the call. I'm guessing the first part is what is stumping you so let's break that out as well:

```
var buffer = new byte[1] { (byte) PacketTypeShimmer2.START_STREAMING_COMMAND };
var offset = 0;
var length = 1;
SerialPort.Write(buffer, offset, length);
```

The first line is simply declaring a byte array with a length of 1 and initializing it using array initialization syntax (which is what the curly braces do after the call to `new`).

The second and third lines are fairly self explanatory , as is the method call itself.

Hopefully that helps break everything down and makes it understandable.

Comment: Actually, any integral value can be cast to any other integral type.  The only time the underlying type for the enum becomes important is for unboxing and p/invoke memory layout.

Comment: Thanks, do you actually need `new byte[1]` at all in this case?

Comment: @geft - You could get away with `new[] { (byte) PacketTypeShimmer2.START_STREAMING_COMMAND };` but you definitely still need to make it a byte array rather than passing the single byte.

Answer (score 3):

[This is the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that specific method.  It says:

> Writes a specified number of bytes to the serial port using data from
>   a buffer.

The parameters are buffer, offset, and count.  Here are the definitions:

- buffer: The byte array that contains the data to write to the port.
- offset:  The zero-based byte offset in the buffer parameter at which to begin copying bytes to the port.
- count:  The number of bytes to write.

Here is your parameters in the one line of code:

- buffer = `new byte[1] { (byte)PacketTypeShimmer2.START_STREAMING_COMMAND }`
- offset = `0`
- count = `1`

The buffer is actually a one-sized byte array (the `new byte[1]{...}` part).  This array contains an `enum` being casted as a `byte`:

```
START_STREAMING_COMMAND = 0x07,
```